# Spring Boot w/ KeyCloak and Redis session store

Tags: spring-boot, redis, keycloak

Can someone suggest how to configure a Spring Boot application to authenticate via KeyCloak, and then use Redis as the session store? I've spent a day googling and banging my head on this, and I just don't feel like I'm getting anywhere.

I know how to configure each one independently - i.e. I can make a boot app that auths via KeyCloak, and I can also make a boot app that keeps session in Redis, but I'm not getting them to work together. Is this possible? It seems like it should be. Or is this just not how its supposed to work?

I think my working POC would behave something like this:

1. start my app
2. access some resource that forces a login via KeyCloak - access to resource is granted
3. restart my app
4. access that same resource but now no login is needed (since session is persisted in Redis)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Interesting ! First question is, what is wrong with getting login form again after restarting your app? modern browsers can remember your username/password. Second, I would imagine where Spring boot handle your browser session id and associate it with Keycloak AccessToken object or just only refreshToken, so after restart your user does get new AccessToken profile by refreshToken, and continue working.

Comment: .. you can do it in simple token filter, just extend OncePerRequestFilter and add to http.addFilterBefore(yourFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) in SecurityConfig. Overall Keycloak is quit fast. We do check expiration time in browser, avoiding extra Keycloak calls. Not sure if I helped :)

Comment: @DmitriAlgazin thx for the suggestion - I'll give it a try.  As for why, the real answer is that we're deploying a group of microservices in Kubernetes, with each service running potentially many instances. So the goal is to allow just one of them to establish a session, and have that used across the cluster. Otherwise each instance must do the whole KeyCloak login re-direct cha-cha.

Answer (score 0):

OK - turns out I'm just not paying attention.  I was not using the access/bearer token correctly.  There is no need to keep the Spring session around when the bearer token is properly provided in requests.